# WPF Data binding to project settings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, binding

In my app, I data bind two text boxes to project settings.

```
<Page.Resources><p:Settings x:Key="Settings" /><Page.Resources/>

<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="textBox1"  Text ="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings},  Path=Default.Number_Of_Versions, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" />
```

In the textbox I see the number of versions which is set as 18 correctly during design time, but at run time the number_of_versions is set as 5.(?). Any idea why I see this behaviour?

I am not setting 5 anywhere in the code and the settings are in user scope.

Comment: The easiest way to debug bindings is to use a dummy converter, set a break point there and read the values (see method 2 at  http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html)

Comment: What does your app.config file say the value is in the userSettings section? You could add some code behind on startup that looks at the value of that setting, something like:  <myApp>.Properties.Settings.Default.<myPropertySetting>();